# About the ergodicity of a system formed by two isolated sub-systems

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ergodicity

Imagine we have an isolated gas with volume $V$, energy $E$, formed by $N$ particles. Suppose $H(q,p)$ is the Hamiltonian, where $(q,p)$ are the $3N$ coordinates and $3N$ momenta of all the particles of the gas.

Now suppose that we divide this gas into two **isolated** sub-systems, the first one with parameters $E_1,V_1,N_1$, and the second one with $E_2,V_2,N_2$. Obviously we have $E_1+E_2=E, \quad V_1+V_2=V, \quad N_1+N_2=N$.

**My question is: is the total gas still ergodic?**

My attempt:

I think the answer is **not**. In fact, by definition, the gas would be ergodic only if its accessible volume was given by $\Gamma(E,V,N)=\text{Volume}\Big(\{(q,p) \in \mathbb{R}^{6N} \mid H(q,p)=E \text{ and } q \text{ is in the volume } V\}\Big)$.

But we have that the accesible volume of the gas is only $\Gamma(E_1,V_1,N_1)\Gamma(E_2,V_2,N_2)<\Gamma(E,V,N)$.

In fact we have that $\Gamma(E,V,N)=\int_0^E\int_0^V\int_0^N \Gamma(E_1,V_1,N_1)\Gamma(E-E_1,V-V_1,N-N_1) \text{d}E_1\text{d}V_1\text{d}N_1>$

$> \Gamma(E_1,V_1,N_1)\Gamma(E_2,V_2,N_2)$.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's worse than that.  The allowed phase space for a single large box is $6N-1$-dimensional, while the allowed phase space for two isolated boxes has dimension $(6N_1 - 1) + (6 N_2 - 1) = 6N - 2$.  In other words, the two sides of your inequality $\Gamma(E_1,V_1,N_1)\Gamma(E_2,V_2,N_2)<\Gamma(E,V,N)$ have different dimensions and can't be even be compared directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I have some doubts now. Why is the dimension $6N-1$? We have $N$ particles, and every particle has $3$ degree of freedom. Again, am I right about the fact that the system is not ergodic?

Comment: In general, a surface $f(x) = \text{const.}$ in an $n$-dimensional space is a submanifold of dimension $n-1$.  In the first case, you have one energy constraint, which reduces the dimension by 1.  In the second case, you have two independent energy constraints, which reduces the dimension by 2.

Comment: Got it! You are right. So is my attempt wrong?

Comment: As far as ergodicity goes, I *think* that ergodicity is usually defined to sidestep these sorts of problems (i.e., it's defined with respect to whatever submanifold of phase space is allowed by the conserved quantities that exist.)  But this isn't my field of expertise, and I'm not sure enough about it to write it up as an answer.